# Limiting objects in a SUM/COUNT without using a WHERE argument but requiring DISTINCT data

Tags: mysql, count, sum, distinct

This may not be possible but worth a shot.

I have a very complex query and am trying to build a specific field. In short, some users have a date for ToS acceptance, other don't (yet) and I need to show both, but with the added complication that I need to have the dates of their logins after the ToS SUM'd. However, I don't want just the total logins, but the total distinct dates.

I can't add the argument t2.session >= t1.ToS in WHERE because that will eliminate the NULL ones I need to have

Here's a simplified view of the query:

```
SELECT t1.user,
     IF(t1.ToS IS NULL, NULL,COUNT(DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(t2.sessionTime, '%Y-%m-%d'))) AS TotalLoginDates
FROM t1
JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.userId
```

Not sure if my best option is a subquery, CASE, or other option.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

EDIT: Some Inputs and desired outputs:

```
t1
id | user         | ToS
1  | John Doe     | 2017-01-01 00:00:00
2  | Dave Smith   | 2017-02-01 06:00:00
3  | Alan Smithee | 2017-03-01 12:00:00
```

```
t2
sessionId | userId | sessionTime
1001      | 1      | 2017-01-01 00:01:00
1002      | 1      | 2017-01-05 03:17:45
1003      | 2      | 2016-12-15 15:27:34
1004      | 2      | 2017-03-15 16:67:12
1005      | 3      | 2017-04-02 12:00:00
1005      | 3      | 2017-04-02 13:15:00
```

```
Desired Output:
t1.user      | TotalLoginDates
John Doe     | 2
Dave Smith   | 1 (only one date after ToS)
Alan Smithee | 1 (2 logins on a single date)
```

Comment: Could you provide example input and output values ?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Added additional information and reviewed the MCVE information. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what you want to do, but this:

> In short, some users have a date for ToS acceptance, other don't
>   (yet) and I need to show both

suggests that you want a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN
     t2
     ON t1.id = t2.userId AND t2.session >= t1.ToS
```

Comment: This looks like it's working, though is throwing me more users than I anticipated. That however could be the result of one of the other JOINs the actual query has.